# Cannot access pre-compiled assets in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I ran `rake assets:precompile` and it generated the assets, but I get a 404 error when it tries to load them. I set `RAILS_ENV=production` before I started the server.

> F, [2017-05-15T04:15:17.160326 #48336] FATAL -- : [05dd2f39-ef90-4e83-8c9f-ebf8b95f04c8] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-872309cf4425a9e40a65887b0a33e1511227d2fa3ba299b0090a6709833ce9bc.css"):

The file exists.

```
>ls -l public/assets/application-872309cf4425a9e40a65887b0a33e1511227d2fa3ba299b0090a6709833ce9bc.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 Chloe Administrators 8345 May 11 17:19 public/assets/application-872309cf4425a9e40a65887b0a33e1511227d2fa3ba299b0090a6709833ce9bc.css
```

Rails 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This worked.

```
>set RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
```

and restart the server. Found this in `production.rb`

```
  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?
```

I was using Puma.